# Cantor set representation

Tags: real-analysis

Why is it possible to write the cantor set $C$ as $C= \frac{1}{3} C \cup (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} C)$? I found this in my textbook and am not quite sure, how to deduce this. 
Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Consider the map $f\colon A \mapsto \frac{1}{3}\cdot A \cup \left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot A\right)$ mapping subsets of $[0,1]$ to subsets of $[0,1]$. The Cantor set is $C = \bigcap f^{n}([0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive definition, and one should show that it is well defined.

If $C \subset \mathbb R$ and $d\in \mathbb R$ you can define $$dC = \{d\cdot x|c\in C\}.$$

And $$d+C = \{d+x | x\in C\}.$$

This way it is pretty clear that the cantor set satisfies the given condition $C = \frac 1 3 C \cup (\frac 2 3 + \frac 1 3 C)$.

Edit: Of course I do not mean that this a definitino of the cantor set, but rather a definition of a set $C$ and obviously the cantor set satisfies it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it's suitable to call it a *definition*. At the very least, a definition would require some additional stuff (e.g. $C = \varnothing$ and $C = \mathbf{R}$ both satisfy this formula)

Comment: It is a definition of a set $C$, and the question was why the cantor set can be written this way. So it is of course by no means the definition of the cantor set, I am sorry if it seemed that my answer implied this.

Comment: My point is that it's not a *definition*: it's just an *equation* that $C$ satisfies.

Comment: I still think you can call it a definition: Lets say we call all subsets of $A \subset \mathbb R$  *C-Sets* iff $A = \frac 1 3 A \cup (\frac 2 3 + \frac 1 3 C)$. Then this is a perfectly valid definition of a set of subsets of $\mathbb R$?